# What commands should I use?

Tags: 12.04, boot, hp-pavilion

My computer (HP Pavilion dv7) does not start correctly, but it at least shows me a list of commands to enter.

For example: `thierry-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC login:` (thierry = my session name)

So I get the name of the session.
Then `Password`. I enter the password.
Then `thierry @ thierry-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC: ~ $` and I do not know what to enter next.

How do I get my computer to start correctly so I can login to my normal desktop environment?

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal window and type the following command, in order to start the GUI:

```
startx
```

Comment: Open a terminal *window*?